# How can I disable the p-checkbox getting the focus to jump screen to center the p-checkbox?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have p-checkbox components in a table and want to disable the component getting the focus and centering the view on it when clicked.

This is in my html:

```
<p-checkbox
    name="select-{{rowIndex}}"
    [(ngModel)]="quotationLine['selectedForDeletion']"
    binary="true" (focus)="onFocus($event)"
    (onChange)="onSelectedForDeletion(quotationLine, $event)">
</p-checkbox>
```

And this in my ts:

```
onFocus($event: FocusEvent) {
        window.scrollBy(0, 0);
    }
```

But it does not seem to disable the checkbox receiving center.

Answer (score 0):

Could not get this component to not consume the focus and destroy the view so used a normal HTML5 checkbox instead and it works flawlessly when used inside a scroll able table.

Comment: that is crazy. I am on prime ng 6 and it kills the whole page on focus. Did you find a way around this?